# How to resolve session issue with cms in magento?

Tags: cms, php

I have created one CMS page for showing coupon code information in Magento. It was successfully created.

But when I open that CMS page, it will be opened another user account’s coupon information. But other links are working correct.

In the url(http://www.example.in/coupon/), if I put "/" at the end its working correct from the account def@gmail.com.
When I open that link from the account “abc@gmail.com” that CMS page open with the "def@gmail.com" account's information.
But if I remove that "/" at the end, its working correct from the account "abc@gmail.com". When I open that link from the account “def@gmail.com” that CMS page open with the "abc@gmail.com" account's information.

I don’t know, why it’s come like this.

Please help me.

Comment: Maybe some full page cache configured wrongly?

Comment: How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a full page cache issue.
A solution would be to create a custom module that displays this information and make that module not cache-able.
You can also try to make that specific page not cache-able but I guess this approach is riskier.
You can find here a small example on how you can create a [module with a page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3135/146). The example is for a page with a form but you can adapt it to display your desired content.