# How to create Custom form

Tags: magento-1.9, forms

I am new to magento.

I want to create a new forms in my magento website. Some form have to add in the cms pages.

I got reference from [This Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/how-do-i-create-a-non-editable-magento-cms-page)

I tried to create pages same like it. but it is not displaying anything.May b its beacause I am using Luxury theme. Help me placing files.

This is my theme path `app\design\frontend\mgstheme\luxury`

I tried placing file here `app\design\frontend\mgstheme\luxury\templateeasylife_customform/form.phtml` as Marius told in that answer

What i am doing wrong?

Thankyou

Comment: Share code which you put on cms page.

Comment: try this... https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-formbuilder.html

Comment: @Dhiren I didnt put anything on cms page yet.... as Marius said in his answer.. i tried open it like `http://127.0.0.1/demo/customform`

Comment: @lalit I tried this plugin. But when i try to open its setting page it gives me error 404 Not Found

Comment: @parish app/design/frontend/mgstheme/luxury/layout/easylife_customform.xml this file in your theme ?

Comment: No i didnt put it there, So i need to put it in here?

Comment: Still nothing no luck.

Comment: what i have to do if i want to call it in the cms page?

Comment: @parish ok clean cache and login again.. it will work.

Comment: yes, you need to put app/design/frontend/mgstheme/luxury/layout/easylife_customfo‌​rm.xml file if you want to access using this http://127.0.0.1/demo/customform

Comment: @DhirenVasoya & lalit  I cleaned catche and restarted my xaamp ... it's working now.. Thankyou for your help :-)

Comment: @parish If you got the solution, please accept solution as answer, so other also get help of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify this things,

Your frontend layout file is put in proper theme or not.
In above case you put file here.

```
app/design/frontend/mgstheme/luxury/layout/easylife_customfo‌​‌​rm.xml
```

Do magento caching and reindexing.
Now try to access with URL.

Answer (score 1):

if you want your form show in yourfile.phtml then paste it's code..

if you want to show this form as separate CMS page then create CMS page from CMS menu > Pages & place the below code in it

```
{{block type="formbuilder/frontend_form" name="frontend_form" form_id="1" template="formbuilder/form.phtml"}}
```

(replace form_id with your form_id, see form_id from Admin panel > Form Builder menu > Manage Forms)